# Does CRuise Control use nAnt or MSbuild?

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, nant

I am having issues understanding Cruise Control.
I would like to create a build automation in order to perform the build in my project. To do that I created the following entry in the ccnet.config file

```
<project name="My Web Release " description="Web config">
  <workingDirectory>d:\GIT</workingDirectory>

  <triggers/>

  <sourcecontrol type="git">
    <repository>GIT REPO</repository>
    <branch>release-name</branch>
    <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
    <fetchSubmodules>true</fetchSubmodules>
    <executable>C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe</executable>
    <tagOnSuccess>false</tagOnSuccess>
    <commitBuildModifications>false</commitBuildModifications>
    <commitUntrackedFiles>false</commitUntrackedFiles>
    <tagCommitMessage> Build {0}</tagCommitMessage>
    <tagNameFormat>Build-{0}</tagNameFormat>
    <committerName>Build</committerName>
    <committerEMail>build@build.com</committerEMail>
    <workingDirectory>$(workingDirectory)\Sources\WEB</workingDirectory>
    <timeout>600000</timeout>
  </sourcecontrol>

  <tasks>
    <msbuild>
      <executable>c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
      <buildFile>BuildScript.xml</buildFile>
      <targets>NewBuild</targets>
      <logger>C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>
    </msbuild>
  </tasks>

  <publishers>
    <xmllogger />
    <artifactcleanup cleanUpMethod="KeepLastXBuilds" cleanUpValue="50" />
  </publishers>

</project>
```

And I do have a BuildScript.xml file.
My question is:
**Is this a nAnt or MSBUILD script?**

I am asking because I am trying to follow the documentation but I get a lot of issues regarding unknown tasks and so on.

For instance, this:

```
<property name="configuration" value="CLOSED" />
```

Would generate a unknown "property" task.

I am looking at MSBuild documentation to use a [Move task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z7f65y0d.aspx).

and I got to this line:

```
<move file="originPath" tofile="TargetPath"/>
```

But I get:

> BuildScript.xml(18,3): error MSB4036: The "Move" task was not
>   found. C heck the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project
>   file is the same as  the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is
>   "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface.
>   3.) The task is correctly declared w ith  in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:
>   \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727" directory.

What is driving me crazy is that it was working before we migrated to Cruise Control.

Is this being interpreted as nAnt or MSBuild? Any ideas on why I am getting these errors?

Comment: as you are using <msbuild>, CC will use MSBuild. What do you have it in BuildScript.xml? if you are using VS, why can't you just build sln instead of using BuildScript.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your mixing nant and msbuild, if it was msbuild it would look like

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" Tools="4.0">
<Target Name="Move">
<PropertyGroup>
   <configuration>CLOSED</configuration>
</PropertyGroup>

<Move SourceFiles="Somefilefile" DestinationFolder="c:\temp"/>
</Target>
</Project>
```

So casing was an issue and that you need to specify the tools version as move is available from 4.0.